# Changing UIView frame ends touching events

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, touch-event

I have a custom `UIView`

```
self.commentView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"commentView" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
self.commentView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width, 52);
[self.commentView setFrame:frame];
[self addSubview:self.commentView];
```

add a gesture recognizer

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapping)];
[self.commentView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

The custom view contains a `UITextView`. I register for keyboard notifications and change my custom view frame when the keyboard appears

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardAppeared:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

---

```
 - (void)keyboardAppeared:(NSNotification*)notificationn{
     NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [notificationn userInfo];
     NSValue* keyboardFrameBegin = [keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
     CGRect keyboardFrameBeginRect = [keyboardFrameBegin CGRectValue];

     CGRect frame = self.commentView.frame;
     frame.origin.y = (keyboardFrameBeginRect.origin.y - frame.size.height);

     [UIView animateWithDuration:.1f animations:^{
         [self.commentView setFrame:frame];
         self.commentView.alpha = 1.0f;
     }];

     keyboard = keyboardFrameBeginRect.origin.y;

 }
```

In my 'tapping' method I have an `NSLog`. When I initially add `commentView` and tap the view, the touches work and `tapping` is called. After the keyboard is shown and the frame of `commentView` is moved above the keyboard, 'tapping' is no longer called - touch events stop.

I also have a notification for when the keyboard is dismissed. In this method, I set the frame back to the original. Touches begin to work again.

**EDIT**
This is how I add the `commentView`. Above `addSubview:` was testing:

```
 - (void) showCommentView{
     CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height-52, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width, 52);
     [self.commentView setFrame:frame];
     if (![self.subviews containsObject:self.commentView]) {
         [self addSubview:self.commentView];
     }
     [self.commentView.commentTextView becomeFirstResponder];

     CGRect framer = [self convertRect:self.commentView.postButton.frame fromView:self.commentView];
     NSLog(@"SUPERVIEW: %f", framer.origin.y);
 }
```

I comment out the line `commentTextView becomeFirstResponder`, and the tap works. If I leave this line, `keyboardAppeared` is called, and the tap no longer works once the frame is changed. So I think the frame of `commentView` isn't actually changed.

Comment: are you using a simulator? if you are you can actually check if you are tapping the commentView by using the color blended layers. probably you are tapping a diff view thats why the gesture is not recognise?

Comment: @Joshua Not using simulator. Set the view to a distinct color as well as bringSubviewToFront. Pretty sure I'm tapping the correct view

Comment: don't want to change the .y value you should change the height of the textview

Answer (score 0):

Set the `color` of the `commentView`. I think your commentView frame is not resize properly when Keyboard appears.

Comment: The `backgroundColor` of the view is a bright orange. I think you're right. The view appears to move above the keyboard but something weird is happening where its frame doesn't actually change.